# Java Syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow not working

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I posted a Java question with Java code:

[My custom made Stack class is always throwing StackIsUnderflowing Exception : Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55694195/my-custom-made-stack-class-is-always-throwing-stackisunderflowing-exception-wh)

Then I selected the code and used the curly brace button and a language: java HTML tag.

But the syntax highlighting is not working. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: You missed to put the [tag:java] language tag at your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your post would be highlighted correctly if you would have done one (or both) things:

1. you would have used the [java] tag (see the bottom of the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info))

   [image]

   Even if it weren't for the syntax highlighting, **please** always tag your question with its programming language. On Stack Overflow, most people are browsing language tags to view questions they can answer, and the home page is also filtered on tags the system thinks a user is interested in. A single language tag might be causing a tenfold increase in the number of views<sup>[citation needed]</sup>.
2. you would have put a hard return before the line with `<!-- language: java -->`. Right now, the Markdown parser treats it as 'just' an HTML comment belonging to the previous paragraph.

Comment: Thank you, everybody, for helping me. I understand now the importance of tag.